# .htaccess - Replace (+) plus with Dash (-) and path of the URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to replace:

```
/search/my+query
```

Then, the url will be redirected to:

```
/download/my-query
```

anybody can help me? im using wordpress, and i expects the code can be work in .htaccess.

Comment: im confused what method in .htaccess if using string replace.